# Prove that the function is no-negative, connections to Fourier transform of $\exp(-|x|^{\alpha})$

Tags: real-analysis, probability, fourier-analysis, special-functions, positive-definite

I need to demonstrate that the following function is nonnegative for $\alpha\in(1,2)$ and $\delta > 1$

$$
\sum_{m=0}^\infty {(-t^2/4)^m \over m!}
\cdot { \Gamma^\prime \left( { \alpha +1 \over \alpha}+ m { 1 \over \alpha} \right) 
+\delta \Gamma \left( { 1\over \alpha} +m { 2\over \alpha}\right) \over \Gamma \left( { 1\over 2} +m\right) },
$$

where $\Gamma(\cdot)$ is a Gamma functions. One can recognize Fox-Wright function in the second term.

Here is the background. I would like to show that the Fourier transform of
${1 \over \alpha^{\delta} } \exp(-|x|^\alpha)$ is nonincreasing in $\alpha$. Taking derivative,
$$
{\partial \over \partial \alpha } \left\{ {1 \over \alpha^{\delta} } 
 \int_0^{\infty} \exp(-x^\alpha)\cos(xt) \, dx \right\}=
-{1 \over \alpha^\delta} \int_0^\infty \exp(-x^\alpha)\{x^\alpha \log(x) + \delta/\alpha\}\cos(xt) \, dx
$$

Using Taylor series expansion for $\cos(\cdot)$ leads to

\begin{align}
&\int_0^\infty \exp(-x^\alpha)\{x^\alpha \log(x) + \delta/\alpha\}\cos(xt) \, dx \\
&= {1\over \alpha^2} \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} { (-t^2)^{m}\over (2m) !}
\Gamma \left( { 2m+1\over \alpha}\right) 
\left\{\gamma\left( { 2m+1\over \alpha}\right) 
\left( { 2m+1\over \alpha}\right)  +
   1+\delta \right\} \\
&={1\over \alpha^2} \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} { (-t^2)^{m}\over (2m) !}
\left[\Gamma^{\prime} \left( { 2m+1\over \alpha}+1\right) 
+\delta \Gamma \left( { 2m+1\over \alpha}\right) \right],
\end{align}

where $\Gamma(\cdot)$ and $\gamma(\cdot)$ are gamma and digamma functions respectively.

There is nothing special about $\delta$, I found it numerically. The connection to Fox Wright function is

\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty \exp(-x^\alpha)\cos(xt) \, dx &=
{1\over \alpha} \sum_{m=0}^\infty
\Gamma\{(1+2m)/\alpha\} { (-t^2)^{m}\over (2m) !} \\
&={\sqrt{\pi}\over \alpha} \sum_{m=0}^{\infty}
{ \Gamma\{(1+2m)/\alpha\}\over \Gamma(1/2+m)}
{ (-t^2/4)^ m \over m !}.
\end{align}

Any hints/ references will be greatly appreciated as well.